# App Store via iTunes Error: Invalid bundle identifier namespace com.yourcompany

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle, app-store-connect, identifier

I'm uploading my first iPhone app to App Store via iTunes Connect, and got this error.

> Invalid bundle identifier namespace com.yourcompany. in bundle identifier com.yourcompany.AAA

In my plist>Bundle Identifier I wrote same as com.yourcompany.AAA

In iTunes Connect I selected 'AAA - com.yourcompany.AAA'

where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a different namespace to make the bundle identifier unique!

Comment: is the AAA namespace? if I change that I need to do the making distribution provisioning profile again?

Comment: com.yourcompany. is the name space and you can change it without risk

Answer (score 0):

`com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` is the default namespace used by xcode when you create a new projet.

Simply change this name space with something different that identify you uniquely, something like `com.bibbac.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` in Your_Project_Name-Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Register a domain name to insure uniqueness.  If you register example.com (you can't), use com.example.AAA (don't. You have to find your own unique domain and namespace.)